# Как убрать класс fixed

Tags: html, jquery, css

Здраствуйте

При скроле добавляю класс для блока `.question-item`, но если прокручивать блок дальше класс fixed не удаляется, т.е  почему не удаляется класс fixed, когда заканчивается блок `section-faq`.

Мой код http://jsfiddle.net/v2jt9noL/

Comment: Вот http://jsfiddle.net/cfqxzhj9/ приблизительное решение, но все это очень корявенько.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все просто. Ваша проблема в постановке условия if. 
http://jsfiddle.net/v2jt9noL/4/

```js
if ((scroll > faqTop) && (scroll < faqBottom)) {
    // Добавляем класс
} else {
    // удаляем класс
}
```

1. Добавлять класс, добавляющий position: fixed необходимо добавить, когда текущий scrollTop будет выше верхней позиции, и **одновременно** ниже нижней его позиции.
2. Достаточно плохо вешать на onScroll добавление класса, тем более через JQuery. Браузер старается инициализировать событие на каждый пиксель перемещения и на каждый пиксель JQuery парсит className элемента, проверяет, есть ли там этот класс и только потом добавляет его. Поэтому, хорошо перед этим действием, проверить на наличие класса: http://jsfiddle.net/v2jt9noL/3/

```js
if ((scroll > faqTop) && (scroll < faqBottom) && !$question.hasClass("faq-fixed")) {
    // Добавляем класс
} else if (((scroll < faqTop) || (scroll > faqBottom)) && $question.hasClass("faq-fixed")) {
    // удаляем класс
}
```